# Timed out while searching for 'workspaceContains' VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Extensions sometime not activated, in Log (Extension Hosts) appear this message

```
[2022-01-07 08:25:00.723] [exthost] [info] Not activating extension 'apollographql.vscode-apollo': Timed out while searching for 'workspaceContains' pattern **/apollo.config.[jt]s,**/apollo.config.cjs
```

and its happen with some extensions too. I checked config file is already in correct folder

**What's I Tried so Far**

- Reload Window
- Reinstall Extensions
- Install Another Version (Ext)
- Completely delete Ext files in `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

**Activation Events `apollographql.vscode-apollo`**

- workspaceContains:**/apollo.config.[jt]s
- workspaceContains:**/apollo.config.cjs

**Workspace Tree**

```
|-- Workspace
    |-- Some Project
    |-- Vue Project
        |-- apollo.config.js
    |-- Some Project
```

Reply in comment, if you need spesific settings.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: who is looking for these file glob patterns, most likely you because your extension is about `apollo` files, what is your `activate` function

Comment: @rioV8,  in `Apollo GraphQL` its, `workspaceContains:**/apollo.config.[jt]s` and 
`workspaceContains:**/apollo.config.cjs` for activation events, see edit for more info, I also added `Workspace Tree`

Comment: what if you split the `[jt]` into 2 separate glob patterns or change it to `**/apollo.config.{ts,js}`, would it be really bad (performance) if you use activation event `"*"` (always), how big are the workspaces that the extension will not activate, what kind of complex work do you do in the activation (I was once able during development hold up the Extension Host from starting: a bug in the activation function)

Comment: @rioV8 After I remove low priority project and change activation to `**/apollo.config.js`, it works mostly everytime, thanks for your suggestion